# Apache2とdjangoプロジェクトをmod_wsgiで紐付けする際のエラーについて

Tags: python, apache, django

ubuntu20.04
Server version: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
Python 3.8
mod_wsgi 4.9.0

上記の環境でdjangoの本番環境を作成しようとしていますが、Apacheから以下のような500エラーが発生しており原因がわかりません。mod_wsgiからdjangoのプロジェクトにあるwsgi.pyは読みに来ているようです。
なお、djangoのrunserverコマンドでは問題なく立ち上がります。

```
mod_wsgi (pid=2259186, process='', application='127.0.1.1:8000|/django'): Loading Python script file '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/django/config/config/wsgi.py'.
mod_wsgi (pid=2259186): Failed to exec Python script file '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/django/config/config/wsgi.py'.
mod_wsgi (pid=2259186): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/django/config/config/wsgi.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/django/config/config/wsgi.py", line 24, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
  File "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/django/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.utils.version import get_version
  File "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/django/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/version.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.utils.regex_helper import _lazy_re_compile
  File "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/django/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/regex_helper.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.utils.functional import SimpleLazyObject
  File "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/django/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 362, in <module>
    class SimpleLazyObject(LazyObject):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    'property' object is not callable
```

以下がwsgi.pyの内容です。

```
import os
import site
import sys

site.addsitedir("/usr/lib/cgi-bin/django/lib/python3.8/site-packages")

sys.path.append('/usr/lib/cgi-bin/django/config')
sys.path.append('/usr/lib/cgi-bin/django/config/config')

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

以下がApache側の.configの内容です。
pythonは/usr/lib/cgi-bin/django/binにvirtualenvでの仮想環境を使用しており、django,mod_wsgiも同環境のものを使用しています。

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/cgi-bin/django/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py38.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so


WSGIPythonHome /usr/lib/cgi-bin/django
WSGIPythonPath /usr/lib/cgi-bin/django/config
WSGIScriptAlias /django /usr/lib/cgi-bin/django/config/config/wsgi.py

<VirtualHost *:8000> 

<Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin/django/config/config>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/django-error.log
LogLevel info
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/django-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

エラーメッセージを検索しても、同様のエラーがヒットしません。
どなたかわかる方がいらっしゃればよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: エラーとは関係無しに検索するとこんな記事が出てくるので、もしかしたら何か参考になるかもしれません。[DjangoアプリをApache Webサーバーで公開する！](https://itc.tokyo/2021/06/15/3313/), [Djangoの本番環境を構築する \[Ubuntu + Apache\]](https://www.petitmonte.com/python/django_apache_ubuntu.html), [python仮想環境上のdjango+apache2でwsgiの設定方法についてお聞きしたいです。](https://teratail.com/questions/283431)

Comment: コメントを頂きありがとうございます。知人とも相談した結果この問題を解決するよりは、Nginxとgunicornでのデプロイを試すことにしました。ありがとうございました。